# Disease treatable by zero-G

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, diseases, medicine

**Background story:** In near future (max 10 years from now) mega-rich person suffers yet unknown disease. He obviously employs every doctor possible and spends loads from his fortune on researching, what is wrong with them.

The scientists come up with some time-delaying solution: Such disease has little or almost no progress, if a patient is in microgravity (= very close to zero gravity). Our hero has now to decide. To die with 90% probability in one year, or, buy a ticket to ISS and stay here for some time and hope for the best. But he could be stuck there *forever*...

**The question:** Is such disease plausible? And ultimately, even if its on verge on implausibility, what symptoms should such disease have? How to make it more plausible?

Comment: My immediate thought is some kind of degenerative bone disease; micro-gravity probably wouldn't slow it per se, but the reduced stress on his bones likely improves his own survivability...

Comment: @Kromey Want to make that an answer?

Comment: @HDE226868 Not really; besides the fact that that's all I can say on that, one of the issues with microgravity is *bone loss*, which is the opposite thing you want if you have a degenerative bone disease!

Comment: Severe coronary problems would be mitigated by zero-g to some extent, as the heart no longer needs to fight gravity to pump blood.

Comment: Heinlein's classic story **Waldo** is about a man who uses zero-G to mitigate the muscle weakness of myasthenia gravis. He also invents mechanical hands, which is why these devices are called Waldoes.

Comment: I think you might want to start by checking the typical health risks for astronauts. Then you need to find or describe a disease where the symptoms are the opposite of of those risks. Say, your patient suffers from too much muscle growth (threatiening his heart, since the swelling muscles reduce the volume of the chambers (please come up with a better idea...), the risk of muscle loss in space could be cancelling such an effect.

Comment: I imagine that breathing is a lot easier in space. So, all those disease and poison that paralyze/starve muscle until you suffocate can be treated easily in zero G

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Such a disease is definitely plausible. Human physiology is heavily influenced by gravity in many ways, none of which we fully understand. It's entirely reasonable to propose that microgravity could prevent the progression of a disease.

As an example, [Fibrodysplasia ossificans progressiva](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibrodysplasia_ossificans_progressiva) is a rare, inherited condition of excessive, improper bone growth. Essentially, whenever the body is wounded, bone is grown at the wound instead of normal tissue. The result is that the patient slowly turns to bone. Surgical procedures to remove the bone only make things worse as the body heals the incisions with more bone growth. There is no known treatment or cure. Now, bone loss is a major issue for astronauts spending prolonged periods of time in space. Part of the problem is likely the reduced requirement for the muscles and bones to hold the weight of the body, but some [researchers](http://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2001/ast01oct_1/) think there may be molecular mechanisms governing bone growth that are sensitive to the gravity and don't work in space. Potentially a microgravity environment could inhibit further bone growth. There are many things we don't know about microgravity's effects on our body, so I think it is definitely possible that Fibrodysplasia ossificans progressiva could be helped by a microgravity environment.

Comment: A similar thought that doesn't necessarily have any scientific basis, but seems plausible: if the same growth factors for bone affect bone tumors, a metastasized bone tumor might be made to stop growing by putting someone in zero-g.

Comment: Wow. That Wikipedia page is one of the most terrifying things I have ever read.

Comment: Scary disease but IMHO there is NO indication what zero-G may have any effects. Only that learning more about the disease **might** (or might not) help prevent bone loss by astronauts in zero-G.

Answer (score 2):

The disease needn't be a virus -- it could be a larger parasite organism attacking the host.  Once you've established that the person is under attack from a parasite, all you need is to invent a creature that dies in zero gravity.

For example, human immune cells can't mature in zero gravity.  A creature whose cells needed to be regrown more frequently than ours might not be able to survive long in such an environment.

Answer (score 2):

**Malignant obesity hypoventilation syndrome.**

from [A case report of malignant obesity hypoventilation syndrome: A weighty problem in our ICUs](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5126148/)

> CASE PRESENTATION: 35 year old African American gentleman with a body
>   mass index (BMI) of 115 kg/m2 presented to the hospital with
>   respiratory distress. On admission he was noted to have multi-organ
>   dysfunction including respiratory failure, renal failure, cardiac and
>   liver abnormalities. His hospital course was remarkable for recurrent
>   cardiac arrest following extubation, complicated tracheostomy, and
>   progressive organ failure despite medical therapy. After a 30 day
>   hospitalization, patient and family decided on terminal extubation
>   owing to worsening medical condition and lack of therapeutic and
>   disposition options. DISCUSSION: The super obese present a number of
>   challenges when admitted to the ICU. Patients with respiratory
>   distress are frequently misdiagnosed and treated for asthma and COPD
>   when obesity hypoventilation syndrome (OHS) is more consistent with
>   the clinical picture. OHS in the superobese is often accompanied by
>   multi-system organ dysfunction, a condition with high morbidity and
>   mortality, with limited treatment options.

From the article; this man was 182 cm, 383 kg (844 lbs).  The weight of the body crushes the lungs and makes it more and more difficult to breathe.  It is much the same situation as marine mammals which are on land and do not have the water to support them.

In zero-G this mega-rich person would not have to move the weight of his body while breathing.  He would probably feel great.

While writing this I was thinking of [Iz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_Kamakawiwo%CA%BBole) who died of complications of obesity.  I bet the water made it easier for him.  Too bad he did not have a space station.
[image: Bruddah Iz]

Comment: But once you realize that earth gravity is about to kill you, how can you reach ISS without sustaining several Gs at take-off?

Answer (score 0):

To get use of such low gravity, person with that rare disease needs to survive

- the stress of astronaut training (which might be a challenge - presumably rich person would not bother if he was in good enough shape)
- the high-G stress of launch.

Contradiction in requirements.

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-force#Typical_examples_of_g-force) that Shuttle had 3G acceleration, which is LESS than high-G roller-coaster. So I guess it should be safe enough (survivable) to launch him up using shuttle, with some risk.

[NASA article about acceleration](http://quest.nasa.gov/saturn/qa/new/Effects_of_speed_and_acceleration_on_the_body.txt) says: "The human body can tolerate violent accelerations for short periods, 
including the the prolonged high-g acceleration necessary to reach Earth 
orbit." ..."Heavy acceleration is a speeded-up aging 
process. Tissues break down, capillaries break down and the heart has to do 
many times its proper work."

So answer is like always **it depends** - in big part on what kind of (undefined) launch vehicle you plan to use. The gentler the better. Now you have framework to ask for more questions to make your story more plausible.

Comment: Boom. Right into feels. Completely forgot that I have to get him up somehow...

Comment: Is there any way then for him to survive the launch, though? Some sort of special suit perhaps to mitigate the launch stresses? Put him in jelly!

Comment: If the disease hasn't progressed enough yet that launch stresses would be fatal, but they know it will, there's no problem.

Comment: The patient may also be less of 'astronaut' and more of 'payload.' I'm told those need less training.

Comment: @Cragor - [Yes.](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/5230/how-could-humans-survive-in-extremely-high-gravity/5233#5233)

Comment: The effects of acceleration can be reduced by being submerged in liquid, if it comes to that.

Comment: The OP never mentions macrogravity. Just because a disease is relieved by microgravity, that doesn't mean it's exacerbated by macrogravity.

Comment: Launch would take short time, so effect was not on disease itself but on well-being on patient. After some research I found that acceleration on launch is comparable and bit less than roller-coaster ride, so it should be survivable. I updated my answer.

Comment: @KSmarts - the patient could also be on life support for that time.

Comment: Yet another of those answer of mine which have same number of up and downvotes. Funny.

Comment: How about a space elevator? What acceleration do they need?

Comment: Even with today`s tech, a truly mega-rich person could buy a gentler ride by building a much bigger rocket.